# Background Geoprocessing Requirements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.4, background-geoprocessing, error-001143

I have just done a fresh install of ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 on my PC (new PC, never had ArcGIS on it before).  I tried to run the Union tool and it gave me an error

> ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.
>   ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.

(yes it said it twice)

Re-running the tool gave the same error (several attempts).

The help doesn't really give much info as to what may have caused it.

[image]

Running with background geoprocessing disabled as suggested in the help is successful, but when enabled again it fails.

[image]

I hadn't yet installed the 64bit Background Geoprocessing, so I've installed that and now the tool works fine without error.

**What are the requirements to run Background Geoprocessing in ArcMap?**  Does Background Geoprocessing in ArcGIS *require* the 64bit Geoprocessing to be installed to run from within ArcMap, or is this just coincidence that it now runs (perhaps due to the restart of ArcMap?

Comment: I loathe background geoprocessing, since I usually need to wait around until it's finished anyway, but I usually need to disable it, even before 64-bit BGDT is installed, so no, 64-bit is not required. There may be an environment complication not addressed by your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227992/background-geoprocessing-requirements#comment353010_227992), in ArcGIS Desktop, I very rarely run Background Geoprocessing and I never install 64bit Background Geoprocessing so whenever I do run it I am running 32bit Background Geoprocessing successfully.